# How use command eval with matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I have any Symbols:

```
In [1]: from sympy import *

In [2]: import numpy as np

In [3]: x=Symbol('x')
```

And I created any matrix:

```
In [4]: a=Matrix([[2*x**2,3+x],[4*x**3,-5*x]])

In [5]: a
Out[5]:
  Matrix([
          [2*x**2, x + 3],
          [4*x**3,  -5*x]])
```

if `x=1` I want to evaluate the matrix `a`. I use the command `eval`:

```
In [6]: x=1

In [7]: eval('a')

Out[7]:
  Matrix([
          [2*x**2, x + 3],
          [4*x**3,  -5*x]])
```

I want to obtain this ouput:

```
Out[7]:
  Matrix([
          [2, 4],
          [4, -5]])
```

What's wrong with what I am doing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to substitute symbol for matrix using symPy and numPy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904924/how-to-substitute-symbol-for-matrix-using-sympy-and-numpy)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [subs method](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.subs):

```
import sympy as sy

x = sy.Symbol('x')
a = sy.Matrix([[2*x**2,3+x],[4*x**3,-5*x]])

print(a.subs(dict(x=1)))
# [2,  4]
# [4, -5]
```

or the [evalf method](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/evalf.html#numerical-evaluation):

```
print(a.evalf(subs=dict(x=1)))
# [2.0,  4.0]
# [4.0, -5.0]
```

---

If you have more than one Symbol to substitute, just add them to the substitution dict. For example,

```
a.subs(dict(x=1, y=exp(5)))
```

---

Note that if you define

```
x = sy.Symbol('x')
```

then you are **binding** the name `x` to the object `sy.Symbol('x')`. If later on you assign

```
x = 1
```

then you are **rebinding** the name `x` to a different object, the `int` 1. The old `Symbol` object still exists, its just the name `x` no longer references it. (In Python names (aka variables) simply map to objects).

Meanwhile if you bind `a` to a  `Matrix`:

```
a = sy.Matrix([[2*x**2,3+x],[4*x**3,-5*x]])
```

that `Matrix` object may use the the `Symbol` whose `repr` is `x`. Note carefully that this `x` is *not* the Python variable, rather it is the `Symbol` object itself.

So reassigning `x` to 1 has no impact on `a`. That is why
`eval('a')` does not substitute the new binding for `x`. Instead `eval('a')` simply looks up the bare name `a` in the global namespace, finds that it maps to the `Matrix` object and returns that `Matrix`.

---

If you want the Matrix to automatically update when `x` is changed, one possible solution would be to subclass `Matrix` and define a new property that performs the `subs` call for you. For example,

```
import sympy as sy
import math

class UpdatingMatrix(sy.Matrix):
    def __init__(self, *args):
        super(UpdatingMatrix, self).__init__(*args)
        self._names = set([symbol.name for expr in self.mat
                           for symbol in expr.free_symbols])
    @property
    def val(self):
        return self.subs({name:eval(name) for name in self._names})

x = sy.Symbol('x')
y = sy.Symbol('y')
a = UpdatingMatrix([[2*x**2,3+x*y],[4*x**3,-5*x]])
x = 100
y = 1
print(a.val)
```

yields

```
[  20000,  103]
[4000000, -500]
```

Note that you have to use `a.val` to see the updated value; I don't see a way to automatically change `a` itself when performing an assignment like `x = 1`. That might not be desirable anyway, since if that were possible, then `a` could not update itself a second time in you were to later assign `x = 2` (since `a` would no longer depend on `x`.) With the solution above, each time you access `a.val`, the substitutions are re-applied, so `a.val` would return the value of `a` with respect to the current values of `x` and `y`.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. but i have other problem:

Comment: Thank u for your answer. But i have other problem:  If what happen if you have two or more variables that you define like symbol and have assign one valor. For example  y = sy.Symbol('y') an y=exp(5) and you have a = sy.Matrix([[2*x**2,3+x*y],[4*x**3+y,-5*x]]). How you do for obtain the new result.

Comment: You can add more substitutions to the `dict`: `a.subs(dict(x=1, y=exp(5)))`.

Comment: if you before defined the variable x=1 and y=exp(5) you can write a.subs(dict(x,y))

Comment: No, that's not true. `dict(x, y)` will raise a `TypeError: dict expected at most 1 arguments, got 2`. If `x = 1` has already been assigned, then you could use `a.subs({'x':x})`, however. The dict key is the string `repr` of the `Symbol`, the dict value is the new value to be substituted.

Comment: But i need to separete the variable's value like x=1 and y=exp(5) of the matrix a, I want the matrix a change the automatic form only change x and y. How do it??