# How to substitute in batch in sympy?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have the following code for some symbolic calculations:

```
from sympy import *
import numpy
A = MatrixSymbol('A',2,2)
f = Matrix(A).det() # for example only, the actual function is of the same flavor
```

How do I substitute `A` with an explicit Matrix of the same dimensions? I tried the following code but it doesn't produce desired result:

```
f.subs(A,Matrix(numpy.random.rand(2,2)))
```

Returned:

```
Matrix([
[ 0.204259256795002, 0.198427966386296],
[0.0929675373783559, 0.516653291115676]])[0, 0]*Matrix([
[ 0.204259256795002, 0.198427966386296],
[0.0929675373783559, 0.516653291115676]])[1, 1] - Matrix([
[ 0.204259256795002, 0.198427966386296],
[0.0929675373783559, 0.516653291115676]])[0, 1]*Matrix([
[ 0.204259256795002, 0.198427966386296],
[0.0929675373783559, 0.516653291115676]])[1, 0]
```

Comment: This might interest you: 
 [SymPy - substitute sybolic entries in a matrix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23208838/sympy-substitute-sybolic-entries-in-a-matrix); [How to substitute symbol for matrix using symPy and numPy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904924/how-to-substitute-symbol-for-matrix-using-sympy-and-numpy); and https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/2962

Answer (score 0):

The substitution worked. It remained unevaluated by default. To evaluate it, use `doit()`, like

```
>>> f.subs(A,Matrix(numpy.random.rand(2,2))).doit()
-0.0866313884475072
```

Comment: Sorry but `doit()` doesn't seem to evaluate the expression in my environment

Comment: Python 3.5.0 (default, Sep 27 2015, 12:06:50) 
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from sympy import *
>>> import numpy
>>> A = MatrixSymbol('A',2,2)
>>> f = Matrix(A).det()
>>> f.subs(A,Matrix(numpy.random.rand(2,2))).doit()
Matrix([
[0.231174234097573, 0.828920556066121],
[0.354529006116848, 0.323184714163859]])[0, 0]*Matrix([
[0.231174234097573, 0.828920556066121],...

Comment: >>> print(sympy.__version__)
0.7.6.1

Comment: Ah, it seems this is a bug that is only fixed in the development version of SymPy.